# jimu mirror threw an uncaught NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, mirror

Just getting into Android Studio plugins and am trying out [jimu mirror](http://www.jimumirror.com/). Right out of the gate I'm getting:

> ```
> > NoClassDefFoundError: update failed for AnAction with
> > ID=MirrorASPlugin.ModuleSelectionAction:
> > com/android/tools/idea/gradle/invoker/GradleInvoker$AfterGradleInvocationTask
> ```

I've tried a clean and rebuild with no luck. I'm thinking jimu hasn't updated for the latest Android Studio. Anybody running mirror on a recent version of studio that can help?

Android Studio 2.3.3
Build #AI-162.4069837, built on June 6, 2017 JRE:
1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the latest version of [jimu Mirror](http://www.jimumirror.com/mirror-downloads/) which should fix this error on Android Studio 2.3 or 3.0.

Comment: Facing the same issue, after updating as well.